# Temporary Accommodation for Wife employment visa

Tags: visa, relocation, employment, accommodation, malta

I am a Third Country National (TCN) with a valid residence permit in Malta. My wife has secured a job in Malta and is currently in the process of applying for her own employment visa. I would like to know if it is permissible for me to temporarily provide accommodation for my wife in my registered apartment, with the permission of the landlord, until she settles.
I kindly request your guidance on whether any specific documents, such as a copy of the marriage certificate, need to be submitted along with the proof of declaration form in this case.